# Modelling a domain model

Tags: uml, agile, class-diagram

I have a scenario which involves a vending machine and then asks us to create to "model the problem domain". I've covered modelling very loosely and was hoping someone would clear this up.

From research it looks like a problem domain is just a domain model which in turn is pretty much a UML Class Diagram.

The examples I've seen look they're almost database schemas with a customer entity, order entity etc etc.

I'm just not sure what the differences are exactly.

So I just wondered if I was on the right track and would anyone mind elaborating on this or perhaps pointing me towards a concise definition. Thanks.

Comment: My pointer: use Google: "site:stackoverflow.com uml domain model" and pick an answer that suites you best and then either delete your question or flag it as duplicate. My other preferred sources for searching the concise definition would be http://en.wikipedia.org, http://www.uml-diagrams.org, http://www.agilemodeling.com

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Those links really helped. You were right about there being loads of similar questions.

Comment: ..or you can draw the "vending machine" domain model diagrams and publish it(them) here as [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I'm going to give it a go! I hope I'll receive lots of positive criticism lol

Answer (score 1):

The "problem domain" is just the stuff you're interested in.  In your case, it's all the stuff a vending machine does, and who interacts with it.

It boils down to a collection of use cases, which can be diagrammed in a use case diagram.  What does the vending machine do? It takes coins from a buyer (the actor), gives change (maybe...so make sure you understand "extension points"), spits out stuff (always, because we aren't in the real world), and so on.  Then maybe you can get creative with a different actor.  A maintenance person takes out money, adds change, fills up the machine, runs a diagnostic stack, whatever.  Each one of these is a use case.  Put them together into a use case diagram.

If you want to go into detail about what each use case does, then use an activity diagram.  One for each use case.

Answer (score 1):

Any system (software or not and modeled or not) has structural and behaviour aspects.

The structural aspects are non-time bound aspects of your system, such as which classes your system is made up of, their associations and dependencies, how they are divided into subsystems, etc. Most of these elements are often referred to as classifiers.

The behaviour aspects shows how these structural aspects collaborates together over time to achieve the goals of the system, such as methods, state machines, workflows, use case realisations, etc.

The structural and behaviour aspects are what you specify when you are writing your code or creating a model.

Objects, are by definition instances of classes. This means that objects are the "things" that actually exists when the system executes. Hence, you do not program an object; you program a class, which when executed, is instantiated into one or several objects.

However, in many modelling languages (but not common in programming languages), you can also model specifications of scenarios, which show specifications of objects and how they interact, for example in UML you may create an object diagram, showing one example of how the system of objects (i.e., instantiated classes) might be structured and collaborate during execution.

Now, a system always strives to a achieve one or several goals for it's surrounding. The surrounding is made up of persons and/or another systems (actors) interacting with the system. This "surrounding" or "background", on which the system is situated in and makes sense in, is often called the "domain".

These "actors" have a "problem" they would like that the system helps them to solve. When this problem is modelled, one calls that model the "problem domain model" for the system. It states the logical structural and behaviour aspects of the problem domain, without stating how it is going to be implemented in a specific implementation of a system. I.e., it is not referring to implementation aspects, like Java, SQL, primary keys, transactions, reflection, angular, etc; it is instead focusing on the core structures of the domain, like Orders, Parties, Contracts, Products, etc.

The problem domain model is one of the most important "contracts" between the system developers and the persons paying for the system or being owners and users of the system. It makes it possible for you all to understand the problem to be solved in the same way and are makes sure that you all are using the same concepts to reason about it. Since it, by definition, is not a technical artefact, you should describe it using as simple notation (but still stringent and crisp clear) as possible so that also non-software professionals could understand and agree on it. Class diagrams (stripped from all technical details) and use case diagrams are two notation techniques available. But also object diagrams and activity diagrams could come in handy.

If you are interested in this, I deliver a course in advanced concept domain modeling on Udemy. Here is link and 90%-off code: https://www.udemy.com/get-your-concepts-straight/?couponCode=CONCEPTS29

Regards
Per

Comment: Goodness! I just noticed this. Thanks SO much for your detailed information and even more for the discount, I'll sign up as soon as I get paid. Thanks again.